# Android Studio: can't write to external database

Tags: android, mysql, database, android-studio, phpmyadmin

i need to retrieve data from mysql database online, using java and android studio.
First of all, I tried to write a record into the database.

These are my files:

init.php

```
 <?php  
 $db_name = "db";  
 $mysql_user = "admin";  
 $mysql_pass = "password";  
 $server_name = "localhost";  
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);  
 ?>
```

register.php

```
 <?php  
 require "init.php";  

 $name = $_POST["user"];  
 $user_name = $_POST["user_name"];  
 $user_pass = $_POST["user_pass"];  
 $sql_query = "insert into user_info values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";
 ?>
```

I put them into the server folder and I tried to access them by:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://www.trotterellandia.it/register.php";
        String method = params[0];

        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String name = params[1];
            String user_name = params[2];
            String user_pass = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                Log.d("Simone", data);

                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Success...";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("Registration Success...")) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

and i call the method with:

```
public void userReg(View view) {
    name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_name = ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_pass = ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();

    String method = "register";

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask(this);`enter code here`
    backgroundTask.execute(method, name, user_name, user_pass);
    finish();
}
```

but any rows is created.
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What type of errors are you receiving?

Comment: I don't get any error I think.. Or, where do I see it?

Comment: Excuse me, are you shure this condition is found? **if (method.equals("register")) {**

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I put a log

Comment: You could Toast to see some more info, if any:

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(ctx, e.printStackTrace(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(ctx, e.printStackTrace(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

Comment: @statosdotcom  Can you please correct your code? Where do I put it?

Comment: I don't pass to the catch clausure

Comment: Title and question are wrong, or misleading at best. You're not accessing an external DB/MySQL from Android

Comment: I wrote that I tried to WRITE not to access

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 0):

**(This is not an answer, just using to show formatted code, thanks)**

Right after your "Registration Success"...

```
        return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, e.printStackTrace(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, e.printStackTrace(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

These Toasts can show something.

Comment: The don't show anything because I don't pass throw catch

Comment: You could continue inserting Toasts inside your **Try** clause, like breakpoints, to see until where your code is running/certify the values all vars are assuming.